# Do I need a transit visa for Paris when travelling to Italy with a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas, paris

I’m an Indian citizen travelling to Italy for leisure. I have a long layover in Paris. Do I need a transit visa?
I do have a Schengen visa for Italy.

Comment: In short, no, because you are not in transit when you arrive in Paris; you will actually enter the Schengen area there.  Your flight from Paris to Italy will not be subject to passport control because it is an internal Schengen flight.